# Make "Hey Siri" activation like, to start recording in iOS app

Tags: ios, speech-recognition, speech-to-text, siri

I would like to make a voice command such as "Hey Siri" or "Ok Google" voice activation without press any key on my app.

For example i want to say "Hey MyAppName" to start recording, Just like "OK Google" or "Hey Siri.

Thanks

Comment: Have a look at the Dragon SDK for iOS.

Comment: Check out SiriKit , https://developer.apple.com/sirikit/ Official documentation from Apple and how to implement it.